# Load a calender control in knockout grid

Tags: knockout.js, calendar

I have a grid developed using knockout. Now i want to place a calendar inside the grid for 2 columns. I have included jquery.findflight-datepicker.js in my application.I am using setDatePicker method from the .js file. On running the application I am able not able to see the calendar on my page.Need help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using koGrid? In koGrid you set templates for column specs. In yours you can try to use the ko binding to use a template and have the template do all the displaying for you.